Component of force
If I have a wedge at angle $\theta$ and a small object of mass $m$ on it I can break the gravitational force into two components $mg\sin\theta$ and $mg\cos\theta$ and block will slide down because of $mg\sin\theta$.
But if I take another component of $mg\cos\theta$ it will be $mg\cos\theta\sin\theta$ and after that one more then it will be $mg\sin\theta\cos^2\theta$. But if so then it will stop $mg\sin\theta$?


This question is similar to: Why taking components of a component of a vector is invalid?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
